# node-orm2 get count of unique occurrences?

Tags: node.js, orm, node-orm2

How can I return a count of unique values in a table? This returns an array of unique IDs...

```
req.models.pages.aggregate().distinct("page").get(function (err, page) {...
// returns [ '6', '92', '90', '91', '93', '94', '102' ]
// the unique ids of the individual pages
```

However, how can I return an object with corresponding counts? Something like...

```
{ '6': 2, '92':7, '90':12, etc...}
// the unique page ids with their associated counts
```

I see how to aggregate and I've seen how to count(), but I don't see where I can do them both together.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the expected results using...

```
req.models.pages.aggregate(['page']).count().groupBy('page').get(function (err, pages) {...
```

Which returned ...

```
[
  {
    "page": "6",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "page": "92",
    "count": 7
  },
  {
    "page": "90",
    "count": 12
  }
]
```